# Multiple select checkbox laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, select, checkbox, laravel-livewire

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer la siguiente funcionalidad en Livewire?

```
public $servicios = [];

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="servicioslb">Servicios</label>
   @foreach($serviciosTotales as $servicio)
       <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">

       <input wire:model="servicios[]" value="{{$servicio->id}}" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input mx-2 px-2" id="servicios">

       <label class="custom-control-label mx-2 px-2" for="servicioslb">{{$servicio->nombre_servicio}}</label>

       </div>
   @endforeach
 </div>
```

En esta forma que intento utilizar, los check se seleccionan todos juntos y no funciona con Livewire. Alguien sabe si se puede hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:
Le agregue el indice al foreach y la propiedad `public servicios = [];` se carga de  la siguiente manera:

```
wire:model="servicios.{{ $index }}" value="{{ $servicio->id }}"
```

Resultado final:

```
@foreach($serviciosTotales as $index => $servicio)
                                                    
      <div>
          <label class="mx-2 px-2">{{$servicio->nombre_servicio}}</label>
          <input wire:model="servicios.{{ $index }}" value="{{ $servicio->id }}" 
          type="checkbox">
      </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola gracias por publicar la respuesta, tenía el mismo inconveniente. Te quería consultar si sabes como es el proceso para actualizar, he tenido problemas para llenar los checkboxs y guardarlos. He tenido varios días pero nada que lo resuelvo. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, no lo hice aún, pero entiendo que es similar ¿probaste como primer paso obtener los checkboxs seleccionados? una vez que en la vista muestras todos los checkbox que fueron seleccionados, el proceso es el mismo pero generando un update.

Answer (score 0):

**Esto para actualizar los checkboxes.**

Tuve un caso similar con la librería **permissions** de **spatie**, lo resolví de la siguiente forma, en este caso tenia que pasar un array de ids para sincronizar los permisos, pero por alguna razón me tomaba el "Key" del arreglo en lugar del "Value".

**Controller**

```
public $permissions = [];

public function mount() {
    $selectPermissions = $this->user->getAllPermissions()->pluck('id')->toArray();
  
    foreach($selectPermissions as $selectPermission) {
        $this->permissions[$selectPermission] = $selectPermission;
    }
 }

public function updateUser() {
    $syncPermissions = [];
  
    foreach($this->permissions as $permission) {
        if($permission) {
            $syncPermission[$permission] = $permission;
        }
    }
  
  
    dd($syncPermissions);
  
}

public function render()
{
    $permissionsAvaibles = [];
  
    $permissionsObjs = Permission::all();
  
    foreach($this->permissions as $permission) {
        $permissionsAvaibles[$permission->id] = $permission;
    }
  
}
```

**Vista**

```
@foreach($permissionsAvaibles as $key => $permission)
  <input type="checkbox" wire:model="permission.{{ $key }}" value="{{ $permission->id }}" />
  {{ $permission->name }}
@endforeach
```